# Ansible: Create a conditional from the output of previous task

Tags: ansible

I want to run a task only if at the previous task it contains a specific output.

E.g.  I am checking if the status is "running". If yes, then run a command

My playbook:

```
  - name: 'Backup'
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
         -
          name: 'CHeck_Status'
          shell: tool ha status |grep -i Status
          register: service_status
         -
          debug:
                 var: service_status.stdout_lines
         -
          name: 'Run ls'
          shell: ls -ltr
          when: service_status.stdout_lines == "Status*running"
          register: output
         -
          debug:
                 var: output
```

The output of the command is

```
PLAY [Backup] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [CHeck_Status] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhos]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "service_status.stdout_lines": [
    "Status: running",
    "Status: running"
    ]
}

TASK [Run ls] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
        "skipped": true
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                    : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

it always fails. Any help on how can I do the conditional for when?

Also if I try this conditional I get the below error:

```
The offending line appears to be:

          shell: ls -ltr
          when: service_status.stdout_lines == "'Status: running'"
                                                       ^ here
```

Thank you

Comment: stdout_lines is a list, you can use:

when: service_status.stdout_lines[-1] == 'Status: running'

Comment: I still have the error(it seems that is doesn't like the space after :)         shell: ls -ltr
          when: service_ha_status.stdout_lines[-1] == 'Status: running'
                                                                                               ^ here

Comment: try this: service_ha_status.stdout_lines[-1] == "Status{{':'}} running"

Comment: "output": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
        "skipped": true

Comment: it works on my side with  "Status{{':'}} running"

Comment: => `when: "'Status: running' in service_status.stdout_lines"` or eventually `when: service_status.stdout is search('Status: running')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the item *'Status: running'* is [*in*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-tests.in) the list, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: Run ls
      shell: ls -ltr
      register: output
      when: "'Status: running' in service_status.stdout_lines"
```